# What is the difference between count and total_count on an elasticsearch range facet?

Tags: range, elasticsearch, faceted-search, facet

I'm doing a search using a range facet:

```
{
"query": {
    "match_all": {}
},
"facets": {
    "prices": {
        "range": {
            "field": "product_price",
            "ranges": [
                {"from": 0, "to": 200},
                {"from": 200, "to": 400},
                {"from": 400, "to": 600},
                {"from": 600, "to": 800},
                {"from": 800}
            ]
        }
    }
}
}
```

And I got as response the ranges, as expected:

```
[
  {
    "from": 0.0,
    "to": 200.0,
    "count": 0,
    "total_count": 0,
    "total": 0.0,
    "mean": 0.0
  },
  {
    "from": 200.0,
    "to": 400.0,
    "count": 1,
    "min": 399.0,
    "max": 399.0,
    "total_count": 1,
    "total": 399.0,
    "mean": 399.0
  },
  {
    "from": 400.0,
    "to": 600.0,
    "count": 5,
    "min": 499.0,
    "max": 599.0,
    "total_count": 5,
    "total": 2886.0,
    "mean": 577.2
  },
  {
    "from": 600.0,
    "to": 800.0,
    "count": 3,
    "min": 690.0,
    "max": 790.0,
    "total_count": 3,
    "total": 2179.0,
    "mean": 726.3333333333334
  },
  {
    "from": 800.0,
    "count": 2,
    "min": 899.0,
    "max": 990.0,
    "total_count": 2,
    "total": 1889.0,
    "mean": 944.5
  }
]
```

In all responses the `count` and `total_count` are the same.
Does anybody know what is the difference between them? Which one should I use?

Answer (score 10):

Very good question! This part is tricky since you see the same values most of the time, but... when you use the `key_field` and `value_field` you can compute the ranges based on a field and the aggregated data (`min`,`max`,`total_count`,`total` and `mean`)  on another field. For instance you could compute the ranges on a popularity field and see the aggregated data on a price field, to see for every range of popularity what kind of price you have; maybe people like cheap products, or maybe not?

Let's imagine your products can have multiple prices, let's say for example a different price per country...this is when you have `count` that differs from `total_count`. Let's have a look at an example.

Let's index a couple of documents that contain a popularity field and a price field, which can have multiple values:

```
{
  "popularity": 50,
  "price": [28,30,32]
}
```

and

```
{
    "popularity": 120,
    "price": [50,54]
}
```

Let's now run the following search request, which builds a range facet using the popularity field as key and the price field as value:

```
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "facets": {
        "popularity_prices": {
            "range": {
                "key_field": "popularity",
                "value_field": "price",
                "ranges": [
                    {"to": 100},
                    {"from": 100}
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the obtained facet:

```
{
    "popularity_prices": {
      "_type": "range",
      "ranges": [
        {
          "to": 100,
          "count": 1,
          "min": 28,
          "max": 32,
          "total_count": 3,
          "total": 90,
          "mean": 30
        },
        {
          "from": 100,
          "count": 1,
          "min": 50,
          "max": 54,
          "total_count": 2,
          "total": 104,
          "mean": 52
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

It should be clearer now what the `total_count` is. It relates to the `value_field` (price): 3 different price values fall into the first range, but they come from the same document. On the other hand `count` is the number of documents that fall into the range.

Now that we also understood the `count` is about documents while the `total_count` is about field values, we would expect the same behaviour with a normal range facet, if the field holds multiple values...right? Unfortunately that doesn't currently happen, the range facet will consider only the first value for each field. Not sure whether it's a bug. Therefore the `count` and the `total_count` are always the same.

Comment: Is this in the documentation somewhere ? If yes do you have a link ? Thanks

Comment: Actually I never read it anywhere, just tried it out myself :) I read something on the "ElasticSearch server book" about multiple values, but that wasn't completely clear to me anyway.